# ListView with VirtualizedWrapPanel without scrolling

Tags: wpf, listview, wrappanel

I have fixed a couple of lines in [this implementation of a VirtualizedWrapPanel.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/75847/Virtualizing-WrapPanel)
Ok, the window in which I have put the ListView with the VirtualizedWrapPanel as the ListView's ItemsPanel shoud not be scrollable. Instead of scrolling, the user will initiate something like pages change by clicking the button. So I'll should somehow bring into view "the next portion of items" as a response to the button click.

Here is the ListView which I have described:

```
 <ListView x:Name="StationsListView"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
              BorderThickness="0"
              DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModelKey}"
              SelectionMode="Extended"
              Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Stations}">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <common:VirtualizingWrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Style="{DynamicResource DestinationButtonStyle}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}"
                               Style="{DynamicResource DestinationStationTextBlockStyle}"
                               TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

So, how can I scroll to the next portion of items manually?

Comment: How about calling [ScrollIntoView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.scrollintoview.aspx) and pass the first item of the "next portion of items".

Comment: How to determine how much elements from the list were really rendered?

Comment: Hmmm, I wrote down ScrollIntoView with the hidden scrollel and nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

After looking through the code example from your link, I'm not convinced of the author's knowledge on the subject of virtualization. The code *seems* to be more complicated and less efficient than it needs to be.

I have a WPF book that explains virtualisation very well with examples and you're in luck, because someone has published it online. I'm not sure if it is legal, so I can't verify how long this link will work, but it does now: Take a look at chapter 8 in [Control Development Unleashed](http://www.adorkable.us/books/wpf_control_development.pdf) online.